# How to open Particular screen from notification when app is in background?

Tags: android, notifications, chat, splash-screen

I am trying to open perticular screen which was starting depends on notification.
I get Notification but not to open the screen so please help me to find out the solution.

```
    public static void sendChatNotification(Context context, String title, String messageBody, int notificaionId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChattingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isFromNotification",true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
       Uri defaultSoundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
        + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/incoming");
           Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
    R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelIdChat)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.vector_app_logo_notification_status_bar)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(messageBody))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.newMessageFrom))
        .setGroup("chat")
        .setGroupSummary(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

- Set up properly of Notification task in android application.
- Send Notification to your device which have app to open screen.
- Open code. and write the command in Splash Screen.

> Splashscreen.java  -> onCreate()

```
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
       
        onNewIntent(getIntent());          //  onNewIntent  is the Main line.
       }
```

- after out of onCreate() method, **Override newIntent()** method by pressing Alt + Insert button.
- write code in ***newIntent()***  metho

  ```
      @Override
      protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
      super.onNewIntent(intent);
      if(intent.hasExtra("action")){
      if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("112")){
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  // opening in **Main Activity** to *redirect* in **Chat Screen**
           intent1.putExtra("action","112");   //  here "112" is the chat notification action.
           startActivity(intent1);
         }
        }
      }
  ```

> - Open ***MainActivity.java***  -> onCreate()

- write code to find out intent with it actions if intent have available data.

  ```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          // check if intent have action in data.
          if(getIntent().hasExtra("action")){  

          // check if data available then action == 112 is available or not.
          if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("112")){   

          // opening ChattingActivity.java if all scenario is not nullable.
          startActivity(new Intent(this,ChattingActivity.class));  
        }
       }
  ```